# xwinwrap doesn't start on Ubuntu with bspwm

Tags: xorg, compton, xwinwrap

When I launch bspwm with xwinwrap, xwinwrap doesn't start. When I simply start xwinwrap it return error:

```
xwinwrap -g 1920x1080 -ni -fs -s -st -sp -nf -ov -- gifview ~/wallpaper.gif -a

X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  1 (X_CreateWindow)
Serial number of failed request:  39
Current serial number in output stream:  41
```

Even if I kill compton xwinwrap doesn't start. Without -ov flag xwinwrap start. But I wanna make live wallpapers on bspwm, so -ov is required in my case.

Comment: You did not mentioned how you use bspwm, so I could not reproduce yor situation.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the next solution to get xwinwrap working:

1. `sudo apt install bspwm` because of you mentioned it
2. `sudo apt-get install gifsicle` because of `gifview: No such file or directory` error appears without it
3. Being in `/home/user` executed: `git clone https://github.com/ujjwal96/xwinwrap.git && cd xwinwrap && make && sudo make install && make clean` to install xwinwrap
4. Downloaded [the gif](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d0/ce/51/d0ce51911d72ec558f914ace338292be.gif) into `/home/user/xwinwrap` folder
5. Executed command:

   ```
   xwinwrap -g 1366x768 -ni -s -nf -b -un -argb -sh circle -- gifview -w WID /home/user/xwinwrap/d0ce51911d72ec558f914ace338292be.gif -a
   ```

My processor and graphics performance is poor, so it lugged on my laptop seriously.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. It's work on i3. I repeat, I need -ov flag. In your solution command doesn't have the flag.

Comment: Ok. I see it now. With that flag I have the same error now.